# Include application in django settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I know two ways to add an application, but what is the **best** for Django 1.9? I've seen both in tutorials, and apparently is the same.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'myApp',]
```

**and**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'myApp.apps.PollsConfig',]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Django 1.9 allows you to configure  your apps using an  [application configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#configuring-applications):

> To configure an application, subclass AppConfig and put the dotted
>   path to that subclass in INSTALLED_APPS.
>
> When INSTALLED_APPS simply contains the dotted path to an application
>   module, Django checks for a default_app_config variable in that
>   module.

This means that if the `default_app_config` in your `myApp/__init__.py` is already equal to `myApp.apps.PollsConfig`, then there is no difference between adding either `myApp.apps.PollsConfig` or simply `myApp` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Thank you very much !, I really thought it had a difference!

Comment: This is the best answer I found after a day. Thanks.